# how to get the reports using testNG with selenium grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

i am running the scripts using selenium grid with TestNG. In testng we are seperating scripts with removing dependency.Format is like that:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="true">
  <test name="Test" preserve-order="false">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.TestCase1"/> 
      <class name="test.TestCase2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
<test name="Test" preserve-order="false">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.TestCase3"/> 
      <class name="test.TestCase4"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

problem is that testng reports only about the last two testcases. Can any one help us how to get reports from all reports ???????. Also testcase1 will effect the testcase2.

Answer (score 1):

From above config xml i can say that your results are overwritten by test 2 as the test name are the same. For instance you must provide unique test name value as below:
`<suite name="Suite" parallel="true">

    <test name="Test-1" preserve-order="false">

        <classes>

             <class name="test.TestCase1"/>

             <class name="test.TestCase2"/>

        </classes

    </test>

    <test name="Test-2" preserve-order="false">

        <classes>

            <class name="test.TestCase3"/>

            <class name="test.TestCase4"/>

        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>`

Furthermore if you are running in parallel without taking care of thread safety then there is a chance of error-prone behavior. You can utilize [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks) to reduce your efforts.

Comment: You mean to say with different test name i can get the two reports for two tests test1 and test2.

Comment: yes you must have different/unique value for "test" tag's "name" attribute. Otherwise the result will get overwrite.